# Filter array to include all strings containing a specific word and check if any strings were matched

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

I have tried to filter the string from the array which consists of the word `DEVICE`.

I have used the following technique to check whether there is a word called having DEVICE in the array but it prints

> Match Not found

even though there are strings having word DEVICE.

Here is the attempt that I have tried:

```
$output= array('football GAME', 'cricket GAME', 'computer DEVICE','mobile DEVICE');
$string = 'DEVICE';
foreach ($output as $out) {
    if (strpos($string, $out) !== FALSE) {
        echo "Match found";
        return true;
    }
}
echo "Match Not found!";
return false;
```

Required Output:

The output should be:

> Match Found.

And also I want to display the list of the items that consist of the word `DEVICE` like:

```
computer DEVICE  
mobile DEVICE
```

What correction do I need here?

Comment: You have your `strpos` arguments back-to-front. It's `strpos(string $haystack, string $needle)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non looping way to solve it is to use preg_grep which is regex on arrays.
The pattern searches for "device" in a case insensitive way and returns any strings that have device in it.

```
$output= array('football GAME', 'cricket GAME', 'computer DEVICE','mobile DEVICE');
$string = 'DEVICE';
$devices = preg_grep("/" . $string . "/i", $output);
Var_dump($devices);
```

Output

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  string(15) "computer DEVICE"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "mobile DEVICE"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/HkQcu

Comment: FYI, `preg_grep` still loops :). You might also want to run `$string` through `preg_quote()`

Comment: @Phil Depends on how you see it. Why loop when you don't have too? The Case insensitive was just a "guess" as generally case sensitive searching an array does not give the result you want.

Comment: I meant that internally, it still loops over the array ~ https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c#L2845. Nice answer anyway, it's very clean

Comment: Sure preg_quote can be usefull. OP has to decide if that is needed. I would say that all array_functions loop. The thing that makes the difference is if it's done faster internal or in PHP and what you find easiest to read.

Answer (score 2):

You've interchanged the arguments in the `strpos()`. The word to be searched is second argument in the function and the string is first.

`int strpos (string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ])`

Use the code below to get required output:

```
    $output= array('football GAME', 'cricket GAME', 'computer DEVICE','mobile DEVICE');
    $string = 'DEVICE';
    foreach ($output as $out) {
        if (strpos($out, $string) !== FALSE) {
              // You can also print the matched word using the echo statement below.
              echo "Match found in word: {$out} <br/>";
              return true;
        }
    }
    echo "Match Not found!";
    return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the position of the strpos fuction's arguments reversed. From php.net:

```
int strpos (string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ])
```

Therefore you should replace LINE 5 with the following

```
 if (strpos($out, $string) !== FALSE) {
```

[1] https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your `strpos()` arguments are backwards. The [API](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.strpos.php) is

> int strpos( string $haystack, mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )

---

As to your other question...

> ...also I want to display the list of the items that I consists of the word DEVICE

you could create an array of the matching elements via [`array_filter()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php)

```
$string = 'DEVICE';
$filtered = array_filter($output, function($out) use ($string) {
    return strpos($out, $string) !== false;
});

echo implode(PHP_EOL, $filtered);
if (count($filtered) > 0) {
    echo 'Match found';
    return true;
}
echo 'Match Not found!';
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the filtered array (of strings containing DEVICE), then you can no longer enjoy the performance benefits of an early `return`.  You must iterate the entire input array -- with a classic loop or an array iterating function. I must state that your requirements do not call for the might of a regular expression; making iterated regex evaluations should be reserved for cases where simpler, native string functions are less suitable.

Boiled down, you need to make iterated case-sensitive checks and include strings which contain your qualifying keyword.

From PHP7.4, arrow functions allow more concise anonymous functions syntax and allow the omission of a `use()` call.

From PHP8, `str_contains()` is available and is perfectly suited to your required matching.

To find out if any strings qualified, just check the boolean evaluation of your output array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tFhUm))

```
$input= [
    'football GAME',
    'cricket GAME',
    'computer DEVICE',
    'mobile DEVICE'
];
$needle = 'DEVICE';

$output = array_filter($input, fn($haystack) => str_contains($haystack, $needle));

var_export(
    [
        'filtered' => $output,
        'found' => $output ? 'yes' : 'no'
    ]
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'filtered' => 
  array (
    2 => 'computer DEVICE',
    3 => 'mobile DEVICE',
  ),
  'found' => 'yes',
)
```